# Is it possible to create a conda environment on a filesystem that doesn't allow symlinks (hard links or soft links)?

Tags: conda, miniconda, python-venv, azure-files

I want to create and use a conda environment on a filesystem (azure files) that doesn't allow symlinks. Is this possible?

The environment is an Azure Container Instance with a Fileshare mounted. I'm trying to create the environment on the file share.

I've tried `conda create /path/to/share -f my_env.yaml` This fails with errors like `Error: create soft link operation unavaliable`.

What I've done that *sort* of woks is creating the env in the containers home space (normal filesystem allowing symlinks) and then copying across to the file share with the copy option to follow symlinks e.g:`

```
conda create ~/temp_env_location -f my_env.yaml  
cp -rL ~/temp_env_location /path/to/share
```

This *sort* of works but it duplicates many thousands of files even for a small environment. Is very slow and I haven't tested it enough to be sure it works well.

Any suggestions for a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No Softlinks

First, I'm a bit surprised that it attempts softlinking at all, since the default configuration option is `allow_softlinks: false`. Perhaps try setting that explicitly:

```
conda config --set allow_softlinks false
```

and see if the `conda create` will work by default. If not then...

### Copy Only

The `conda create` command has a flag for what you're doing:

```
Package Linking and Install-time Options:
  --copy                Install all packages using copies instead of hard- or
                        soft-linking.
```

So you can do

```
conda create --copy /path/to/share -f my_env.yaml
```

and avoid having to do the copying manually. Unfortunately, I think this will ultimately result in the same disk usage.

#### Copy Always

If you will always need to use this option, then you can permanently set the `always_copy` option in the configuration:

```
conda config --set always_copy true
```

Comment: "always_softlinks" can't ensure no link is used. Here is what I read from `conda config --describe`. "When allow_softlinks is False, conda still uses hardlinks when possible, but when it is not possible, conda copies files."

Comment: @Simba I assume you meant `allow_softlinks` not `always_softlinks`. Otherwise, agreed, but it seems ambiguous what "*when it is not possible*" covers. Clearly the OP is a case where it isn't possible to use a hardlink, but perhaps Conda doesn't recognize it. I find curious the OP's literal error: `soft link operation unavailable`, which could indicate `allow_softlinks` has been enabled. Hence, I suggested explicitly turning it off, but don't claim it will necessary solve the issue, since there's that ambiguity as to whether Conda really recognizes the situation.