# Changing files in one environment reflected on others

Tags: python, conda

I have intalled 15 different environments (say env-1 to env-15) and on each of them a specific package is installed as well. I want to change a certain file in each environment, so instead of having the same version in all of them, I have different versions of that file in each environment.

What happens though is that when I change the file in one environment, the files in other environments change too! That's super wierd to me.

Any idea why this happens?

I move the files from my computer to server with filezilla, but I don't think that's the issue. So for example when I open a file with vim on the server, the last modified time changes in all other environmets.

another note: I have another envirenoment with a different python version, and the file there remains unmodified. But I don't know if its about python versions being the same, because I assumed each environment is independent of the other.

Comment: Perhaps the changed file, or some parent directory of it, is a symlink?

Comment: How can I confirm if it's a symlink?

Comment: In any case, we would need to see the full path to the file, in two different environments.

Comment: Assuming unix, you would do a `ls -l` on the file itself and all parent directories.

Comment: _I assumed each environment is independent of the other_ Showing the full path to the file in two different environments will answer this question.

Comment: Here is the full path: 

`~/miniconda3/envs/env-1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/my-package/path-to-file` 

`~/miniconda3/envs/env-2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/my-package/path-to-file`

Comment: And are any of those directories symlinks?

Comment: I don't know. How can I know if it's a symlink or not? I do `ls -l` but I can't understand how a symlink looks different.

Comment: Okay, I searched and I see that number of links is 22 for each file (Which is the number of my environments + 1). So that's a hardlink. But how can I avoid them?

Comment: If something is a symlink, the `ls -l` output will have an arrow `->` followed by the real linked filepath.

Comment: I don't know enough about how venvs work to answer that last question.

Comment: Yes, Conda hardlinks by default. As a rule of thumb, directly editing files within an environment is usually a wrong solution and often an XY problem. However, OP doesn't give enough details to judge. If one needs customization in an environment, then this is usually better (i.e., more reproducibly) done by installing custom packages in each environment (`pip install -e` or `conda develop`) and explicitly managing these outside the environment.

Comment: That's right. Though that's an internal package and I'm trying different files to check output.

Comment: *”That’s right.”* - what is? Is the package being edited not a Conda package? Could you please add to the question the commands used to install this extra package?

Comment: That's right that editing files directly is not a good practice. The package is installed via Conda, but I'm not using different versions. Now that I reread your message, I guess I don't understand how "installing custom packages in each environment" works. Because the point of having multiple environments for me was that I could run my codes in parallel (by activating a different env in each slurm job), but if I have all of them under one environment, how can I run them in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Update 7/15/2023: It still hardlinks the environments even when I pass `--copy`.

---

I found that when you install a package in a new conda environment, if the package is already installed in another environment, conda just links to the previous package, instead of making new files, to save memory (It seems it hardlinks by default, but can soft link too).

You can realize is it's hardlinked or not, by looking at the number of third column when you `ls -l` a file in your package. If it's more than 1, it means it is linking to some other file.

To avoid linking, you should pass `--copy` when you install a new environment.

`conda create --copy -n <env_name>`

Thanks to everyone who helped me understand the issue.

Similar question:
[Is it possible to create a conda environment on a filesystem that doesn't allow symlinks (hard links or soft links)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58133201/is-it-possible-to-create-a-conda-environment-on-a-filesystem-that-doesnt-allow)